# Android: Displaying a 2-D animation on top of Existing View/Activity

Tags: java, android

I've been banging my head against the wall for a couple hours trying to figure out the best way to overlay an animation on top of a current View. I have a ListView, and I want to display an animation (say a frame-by-frame bomb explosion) on top of the ListView when a user clicks a button.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your looking for:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

From the link:

The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed. The view hierarchy will take care of correctly compositing with the Surface any siblings of the SurfaceView that would normally appear on top of it. This can be used to place overlays such as buttons on top of the Surface, though note however that it can have an impact on performance since a full alpha-blended composite will be performed each time the Surface changes.

Or you could subclass the ListView and use the canvas to draw what ever 2d stuff you want:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html